# Could not load table into hive present in Azure blob

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-blob-storage, hiveql

I have a file named new_data.csv in mycontainer and i am trying to load it into hive for writing further query but it is showing an error
 "*Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:wasb://mycontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/new_data.csv is not a directory or unable to create one)*"
 but it exists. Please help

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE new255
  (year INT,
  month INT,
  month_name STRING,
  south FLOAT,
  west FLOAT,
  midwest FLOAT,
  northeast FLOAT
  )


  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LOCATION 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/new_data.csv';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It was just a silly error by me, the error was the location should be 
LOCATION 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/';

And it will work :)